# How to get the steps list of a Cucumber scenario with Cucumber 1.3.17?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, hook

I have a Hook of an AfterStep that was working perfectly with an older version of Cucumber.

```
AfterStep do |scenario|
  scenario.steps.each do |step|
     puts "This is the step #{step.name}" unless !step.currently_active
  end
end
```

The problem now is that the new Scenario class ( [Cucumber::Ast::Facade::Scenario](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/cucumber/cucumber/Cucumber/Ast/Facade/Scenario) ) doesn't have the steps list as a public variable.

How can I get a list of the steps (and to know the current one) on an AfterStep hook, in this new version?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Cucumber 1.3.19 passes a Cucumber::Ast::Scenario not the facade version.  However the step objects in the step collection do not implement "currently_active".

Comment: So, is there a way I can do the same I did in the previous version? :)